# Printing Infopath form 2010(.xml) in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: printing, sharepoint-2010

My question is related to printing an Infopath 2010 form in Sharepoint 2010.I designed an Infopath 2010 form in Infopath Designer 2010 and published it to a form library in Sharepoint 2010.The end user fill the form and store it in .xml format in the document library.Now I would like to print the form filled by the end user?
           Any Ideas or suggestion about the above scenario?Please consider both browser based forms and normal forms

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For normal forms, you have to create a print view. It will create a Word document that can be printed from user's workstations. Here is a link how to design a view for printing:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/design-a-view-that-is-optimized-for-printing-HA010151438.aspx

Unfortunately Word print views are not supported for web-based forms. Usually the only option is to create another InfoPath view and design it for "print": all controls as labels or read only; all sections are visible, etc.

[Update]
@Surendra J: Ok. There are two things to address separately.

First of all user should be able to request "Print" operation right from SharePoint view (and I don't mean "Browser->File->Print"....) This can be implemented by using a custom ECB action. Your custom action will be associated with Forms library or even specific ContentType. It will allow SharePoint users to choose "Print Form" right from SharePoint view. These links should help:

http://www.slideshare.net/gvarosky/introduction-to-developing-custom-actions-within-sharepoint

http://www.csharpest.net/?p=95

Second issue is to make print view from XML. As you can understand InfoPath XML has to be transformed to HTML or image. Preferably it should be done by InfoPath forms library. There is no easy way to navigate to given InfoPath view without mixing rules and URL parameters. I recommend you to take a look at this article:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/156983db-5a62-498f-a3b5-96ad7f57d15f

Disclaimer: I personally like PDF forms product from http://PdfSharepoint.com. It does not have print issues as all forms are dynamic PDFs and works with Adobe Reader. I believe it is a good alternative to InfoPath if printing is necessary.

Comment: Thank you.But my problem is not printing the form from infopath.Its about printing the form form sharepoint document library? please suggest in that way?

Comment: Do you mean print list of properties associated with document, or print actual InfoPath form but directly from Sharepoint view?

Comment: Hi Dmitry,  I mean printing the Infopath form directly form SharePoint view.I think of first converting it into PDF and then printing? What do you say.